# How to redraw/update on particular portion of Form

Tags: c#

Basically I was trying to visualize Bubble Sort Algorithm with help of lines. I am new with Graphics. I am able to produce random and vertical lines and sort them in ascending order and display both sorted and unsorted lines. I am trying to visualize the swap process but when ever I try to update the form it redraws everything from scratch and dont even update anything on screen. But when i call the Update(); function after sorting I can see it is sorted.
[image: Unsorted]

[image: Sorted]

```
private float[] values;
private int m=0;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    values =new float[Width];
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = rnd.Next(Height);
    }
}
void bubbleSort()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        for (m = 0; m < values.Length; m++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < values.Length - m - 1; j++)
            {
                if (values[j] > values[j + 1])
                {
                    float temp = values[j];
                    values[j] = values[j + 1];
                    values[j + 1] = temp;
                    Invalidate();
                }
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    });
    //Update();
}
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //var graphicsObj = this.CreateGraphics();

    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, (float)0.5);

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, i, 0, i, values[i]);
    }
    if (m<values.Length)
    {
        bubbleSort();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added Delay to bubble sort now I can see it redrawing and sorting but still the problem is that it redraws all of the points again.

Comment: `var graphicsObj = this.CreateGraphics()` No! You need to use the '`e.Graphics` object! Also: Better use `Invalidate()` to trigger the `Paint` event, not `Refresh`

Comment: @TaW okay fixed it

Comment: @TaW I tried using both but didnt seem to work

Comment: Aslo dispose of the Pen or use `using` clause: `using (Pen blackPen = new ...){...}`

Comment: And trigger the whole thing by adding maybe a  `Invalidate();` after the initialzation. Also: Don't rely on `m` in the Paint event or even call the sort there. This will be called whenever the form redraws...! After re-ordering the stuff all works fine..

Comment: This is harder to do then it looks.  The paint event handler calls bubblesort and bubblesort directly calls the paint event handler.  Make the array big enough and you get to see this web site's name back.  Using a Task is not correct either, that's a threading race when both the Paint event handler and the task access the array.  Albeit that it is hard to see the consequence.  Consider a Timer, in the Tick event handler make one pass through the bubble sort algorithm and call Invalidate().  That is slow, but you only need to keep human eyes occupied.

Comment: @TaW Then from where I should i call bubble sort again and again? Also I edited a note

Comment: @HansPassant Can u suggest me something different? Like from where should i call bubblesort ? And alos I've never used Tick Event so will need to look in to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you expect, but this does look interesting:

[image]

```
float[] values =new float[555];
int m=0;

private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = rnd.Next(Height);
    }
    m=0;
    bubbleSort();
}
```

The sort itself is unchanged (from the original post!), just the update trigger is moved:

```
void bubbleSort()
{
    for (m = 0; m < values.Length; m++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < values.Length - m - 1; j++)
        {
            if (values[j] > values[j + 1])
            {
                float temp = values[j];
                values[j] = values[j + 1];
                values[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        Refresh();   // Invalidate would be optimized away
    }
}
```

The `Paint` should show the current state and not call the sort:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, i, 0, i, values[i]);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, i,  values[i], i, ClientSize.Height);
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- If we trigger `Paint` deeper inside the loop, things get painfully **slow**.
- If we use `Invalidate`, usually the recommended way to update graphics, the build-up would be instantaneous.
- Also: Do turn on `Double-Buffering` on the `Form` to avoid flicker!